# Is it possible to incorporate autocomplete control inside of kendogrid for inline editing

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

1) I'm using kendogrid with inline editing functionality.I need a scenario to use autocomplete control inside a grid.How to achieve this can any one help?

2) When I select an item inside autocomplete of one grid column based on selection I'm getting data. I need to update the data of other columns of the same grid row based on this data.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you're using template-driven forms, you can use templates inside your grid columns definitions :

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    <template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <kendo-autocomplete
          [data]="listProducts"
          [placeholder]="'e.g. Milk'"
          [(ngModel)]="dataItem.ProductName"
          (valueChange)="handleProductChange($event)"
        >
    </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

2) If you need to apply changes on your row when selecting a value in autocomplete, you can use the valueChange event.
Begin with storing the edited row index when editing the line :

```
protected editHandler({sender, rowIndex, dataItem}) {
    (...)
    // track last edited row
    // it will be used in `closeEditor` for closing previous edited row
    this.editedRowIndex = rowIndex;

}
```

Then use this row index to make changes on the edited row :

```
handleProductChange(value) {
    // Do needed changes in model
    doSomethingWith(this.gridData[this.editedRowIndex]);
}
```

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-template-forms/#toc-configure-the-columns-editor-template

Comment: when i select an item inside autocomplete of one grid column based on selection i'm getting data . i need to update the data of other columns of the same grid row based on this data. .can any one help me How to do this?

Comment: Did this work ? I am trying to implement the same functionality and the above code just generates a textbox not autocomplete in the grid.